# align dotted circle and botted Line equally in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to align the dotted circle and dotted line like the image shown below. Tried aligning in a row but it somehow merged with a row and it's not displaying exactly like the image. The first line is aligned well but not below the other ones. Here is the code for displaying the widgets dotted line and circle.

[image]

```
import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_utils/src/extensions/internacionalization.dart';
import 'package:matab/ui/general_widgets/custom_gradient_button.dart';
import 'package:matab/ui/pages/all_orders/one_order.dart';
import 'package:matab/ui/pages/styles.dart';
import 'package:dotted_line/dotted_line.dart';
import '../../../models/order.dart';
import '../home/home.dart';

class TrackOrder extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrackOrder({Key? key, required this.order}) : super(key: key);
  final Order order;
  @override
  State<TrackOrder> createState() => _TrackOrderState();
}

class _TrackOrderState extends State<TrackOrder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Track Order')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text(
            widget.order.orderID,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: darkGreyColor,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text('Sat, 12 Mar 2022',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: darkGreyColor,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Text('Estimated Time: 07 Days',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: mainColorShades[9],
                  fontSize: 23,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(240, 0, 0, 0),
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  child: DottedLine(
                    dashColor: Colors.black,
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    lineLength: 25,
                    lineThickness: 3,
                    dashLength: 5,
                    dashGapLength: 5,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            //    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(240, 05, 0, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                OrderStatusBar(title: "Received", status: true),

                // Container(
                //     //  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60, 05, 0, 0),
                //     )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              OrderStatusBar(title: "Shipped", status: false),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
              //    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(65, 05, 0, 0),
              ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                // width: 50,
                height: 50,
              ),
              OrderStatusBar(title: "Delivering", status: false),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
              //     margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(65, 05, 0, 0),
              ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              OrderStatusBar(title: "Delivered", status: false),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(widget.order.deliveryAddress.address,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: darkGreyColor,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              18.0,
            ),
            child: CustomGradientButton(
                buttonText: "Done".tr,
                buttonFunction: () => {Get.offAll(Home())}),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Text(
                'Back to Home'.tr,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: mainColor,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onTap: () => Get.offAll(Home()),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar({Key? key, required this.title, required this.status})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;
  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
        ),
        widget.status ? dottedCircleWithCheckMark() : dottedCircle(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

dottedCircle() {
  return DottedBorder(
      borderType: BorderType.Circle,
      dashPattern: const [5, 5],
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
      ));
}

dottedCircleWithCheckMark() {
  return DottedBorder(
      color: Colors.red,
      borderType: BorderType.Circle,
      dashPattern: const [5, 5],
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 40,
        ),
      ));
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for DottedLine widget ?

Comment: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(240, 0, 0, 0),
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  child: DottedLine(
                    dashColor: Colors.black,
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    lineLength: 25,
                    lineThickness: 3,
                    dashLength: 5,
                    dashGapLength: 5,
                  )),
            ),
          ),

Answer (score 1):

The following would do the trick:

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
class TrackOrder extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrackOrder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TrackOrder> createState() => _TrackOrderState();
}

class _TrackOrderState extends State<TrackOrder> {
  static const darkGreyColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(child: Text('Track Order')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 50),
          const Text(
            'orderID',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: darkGreyColor,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 50),
          const Text('Sat, 12 Mar 2022',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: darkGreyColor,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          const Text('Estimated Time: 07 Days',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const OrderStatusBar(title: "Received", status: true),
                dottedLine(),
                const OrderStatusBar(title: "Shipped", status: false),
                dottedLine(),
                const OrderStatusBar(title: "Delivering", status: false),
                dottedLine(),
                const OrderStatusBar(title: "Delivered", status: false),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          const Center(
            child: Text('deliveryAddress.address',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              18.0,
            ),
            child:
                ElevatedButton(child: const Text("Done"), onPressed: () => {}),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: const Text(
                'Back to Home',
                style: TextStyle(
                    // color: mainColor,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onTap: () => {},
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar({Key? key, required this.title, required this.status})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;
  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        widget.status ? dottedCircleWithCheckMark() : dottedCircle(),
        const SizedBox(width: 30),
        Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: widget.status ? FontWeight.bold : null,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

const size = 25.0;
const strokeWidth = 1.0;
const checkedColor = Color.fromRGBO(232, 113, 65, 1);

Widget dottedLine() {
  return const Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27 / 2),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: size,
      child: DottedLine(
        dashColor: Colors.black,
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        lineLength: size,
        lineThickness: strokeWidth,
        dashLength: 5,
        dashGapLength: 5,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

dottedCircle() {
  return DottedBorder(
      borderType: BorderType.Circle,
      dashPattern: const [5, 5],
      child: Container(
        height: size,
        width: size,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
      ));
}

dottedCircleWithCheckMark() {
  return Container(
    height: size + strokeWidth * 2,
    width: size + strokeWidth * 2,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: checkedColor,
    ),  
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: size / 4 * 3,
    ),
  );
}
```